# Collection of type entity symfony2.1

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

**My problem**: I want to know if it's possible to embed a collection of type entity in the form builder.

I have two entities: A `Partitions` Entity which got many `Genrepartition` Entities

```php
/**
 * Partitions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="partitions")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Partitions
{
// ...

/**
 * @var \Genrepartition
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genrepartition", mappedBy="idGenre")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idGenre", referencedColumnName="idGenre")
 * })
 */
private $idgenre;

// ...

/**
 * Set idgenre
 *
 * @param \Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre
 * @return Partitions
 */
public function setIdgenre(\Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre = null)
{
    $this->idgenre = $idgenre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idgenre
 *
 * @return \Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition
 */
public function getIdgenre()
{
    return $this->idgenre;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->idgenre = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add idgenre
 *
 * @param \Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre
 * @return Partitions
 */
public function addIdgenre(\Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre)
{
    $this->idgenre[] = $idgenre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove idgenre
 *
 * @param \Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre
 */
public function removeIdgenre(\Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Genrepartition $idgenre)
{
    $this->idgenre->removeElement($idgenre);
}
```

On the `PartitionsType`, I tried two ways to embed the collection, first "the Documentation Style":

```php
 ->add('idgenre', "collection", array("type" => new GenrepartitionType()))
```

And at second this code:

```php
 ->add("idgenre", "entity", array(
      "class" => "AcmePartBundle:Genrepartition",
      "property" => "libellegenre",
      "query_builder" => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                              return $er->createQueryBuilder("u");
                         }
```

But the problem is that I need to have a collection of a collection.

I wondered if it was possible to embed like that:

```php
->add("idgenre", "collection", array("class" => "entity" ...
```

Currently, I use the second method in my `buildForm` and in the `Controller`, I added the collection of collections myself, which I tried to render with twig without success.

Here's my Controller:

```php
    $Partition = new \Acme\PartBundle\Entity\Partitions();

    //...
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository("AcmePartBundle:Genrepartition")->findAll();
    foreach($em as $value) $Ajouter->getIdpartition()->addIdgenre($value);
    // ...
```

And here's the twig file:

```php
    <select id=".." name="..">
         {% for elem in formPart.idpartition.idgenre %}
              <option value="{{ elem.vars.value.idgenre }}">{{ elem.vars.value.libellegenre }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
    </select>
```